# How to make a line in a table with CSS

Tags: css

I'd tried to make a line as an image below which runs through the table but it didn't work.

I would like to

1. make **a line** like the image.
2. set **a bullet** for each `<td>` in the **2nd** `table`

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <table class="a">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 300px">Shuttle Bus Schedule | Make an appointment</td>
            <td style="width: 220px">My Request</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</tr>
<tr>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 300px">Need Approval by Manager</td>
            <td style="width: 220px">Need Approval by Coordinator</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Approved by Manager</td>
            <td>Approved by Coordinator</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rejected by Manager</td>
            <td>Rejected by Coordinator</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.a {
border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
```

Comment: The content doesn't seem to warrant a table (you're not relating a bunch of data). Why not set headings and use lists?

Comment: u may want to border-bottom the <td>

Comment: @jacob It would depend on the context if the items need to be compared side by side as well. If they do, the CSS to get list items in two side by side lists to match up would be impractical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure your table properly with table headings (`<th>`) instead of nested tables:

```
<table>
   <tr>
        <th style="width: 300px">Shuttle Bus Schedule | Make an appointment</th>
        <th style="width: 220px">My Request</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Need Approval by Manager</td>
        <td>Need Approval by Coordinator</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Approved by Manager</td>
        <td>Approved by Coordinator</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rejected by Manager</td>
        <td>Rejected by Coordinator</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
th {border-bottom:1px solid #c4c4c4};
td:before {content:"\2022";}
```

[You can see this here on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pyj7e/2)

Comment: Thank you for your code but the "Shuttle Bus Schedule | Make an appointment and My Request" are not the heading. Your code suits with my second question...

Comment: @PMay1903 If they are not headings, I'm starting to think that you are using tables for layout. Which is very bad practise.

Comment: So as your opinion, could you please let me know that which one is suitable than the table?

Answer (score -1):

The table structure is not really in good format. However to keep the same table structure you can achieve the results. See the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yomehipe/1/edit)**.

**Here is the CSS need to used.**

```
.a {
border-top: 1px solid transparent;

}
table{border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-collapse:collapse;}

table td{ padding:5px; margin:5px;}

table+table td:last-child{border-left:
  1px solid #c4c4c4;}
table+table td:last-child:before{content:"\2022"}

table+table{border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4; }

table.a td:last-child:before{content:"  "}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code looks good. However, as I've seen, there is only a bullet for each `td` tag in the right side. Could you please let me know how to modify the table structure to make it better?

Comment: If you are building a mailer then its okay using the nested table; otherwise building a webpage you shouldn't be use table anymore.

Comment: Nested tables are never the answer.

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr I've spent my time not to receive the `-1`. 

The answer is accurate and fulfill the User requirement.